# CtabFolder and stack layout

Tags: swt

I am just wondering is there anyway to use both stack layout and CTabFolder as I have my application built using stack layout and composites and I now want to change it to CTabFolder. how would I do this or can it be done?

Regards,
Ann.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, the tabs can contain `Composite`s with any layout you want. You can't set a layout on `CTabFolder` itself, because it has its own layout.